# How to get the address of function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

The address of function is its name with bracket. However, when I use cout to print out the address, it is wrong.

Assuming the function is "int function_address()" and code is such as b

```
cout<<function_address<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

> The address of function is its name with bracket

The address of a function is *not* its name. It is a memory address like e.g. `0x0000000000020d57` (on Linux, you could use `nm` to get addresses of global functions) in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of the process running your program.
**Function *names* are forgotten at runtime** (excepted when related to [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker), and that notion is not in standard C++, but is implementation related). You can even [strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_%28Unix%29) the symbol table of an executable. Function names matter only at compile time and at link time.

In general you cannot get the name of function from its address.

Of course, in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), when you have an expression with only a function name (e.g. the exponential [std::exp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp)) that expression has the function's *address* as its value. Or for example:

```
extern void fun(int); /// declare the function fun, defined elsewhere.
auto fp = fun;
```

then `fp` is a pointer to a function taking one argument, an integer, and that returns nothing (void). Like `fun` this pointer `fp` holds the address of the function (*not* a name), and the initialization of the pointer `fun`  with the address of the function fun() is done at *build* time (e.g. by the compiler and the linker, nothing happens at runtime). Hence `std::cout << fp << std::endl` would output some boolean flag (not a name). And so would `std::cout << fun << std::endl`. And `std::cout << (void*)fp << std::endl` would output some address.

Read Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book to understand more about symbols (such as function names).

On Linux specifically, you might use [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) to get the ([mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)) name of a function address (assuming it has some *global* name in some [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file, and you did not `strip` the binary, and linked with appropriate options - e.g. `-rdynamic`).

In C++11, some functions don't have any names (and some might not have any *global* name). Read about [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) & [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). See also [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: but the code of "ptr=func_name;" can be actually work

Comment: But that does not compute a function name.

Comment: @MichaelTsai That is simply an implicit conversion. The compiler transforms it into `ptr = &func_name;`

Comment: " `std::cout << fp << std::endl` would output some address"  **is not true,** not to speak of the `std::cout << fun << std::endl`.Defaultly the cout will just print **1 or 0**

Answer (score -2):

```
void fun(){
}

int main(){
void *ptr = (void*)fun;
std::cout << "adress of fun is: " << ptr << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```